# What is the better/best way of slicing Swift Data by size?

Tags: swift

I want to slice a `Data` type variable by specifying the memory size. Let's say I want to have only initial 1,000 bytes of an audio file. I'm trying the following code. Both variables point to the same memory address but the sizes differ as expected so seems to work but not sure if it really does.

```swift
let original = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://example.com/audio.mp3")!)
let sliced = original[0..<1_000] // e.g. Only 1000 bytes (I understand the range can not be beyond the actual original data size)
```

- Does the above code work as I expect?
- Any concern with the above approach?
- Any better way to realize the same?

Comment: Not related to your post but you should never use a synchronous initializer to download remote resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Data` slice (as returned by the range-subscript operator you're using, and methods like `prefix`, `suffix`, etc.) shares storage with its “parent” `Data` unless the slice is small enough to be stored inline in the `Data` struct itself. (I believe the maximum size for inline data on 64-bit platforms is 14 bytes.)

You can find the implementation of `Data` for Apple platforms here:

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/Data.swift

For other platforms, the implementation is here:

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Data.swift

Comment: prefix() should work enough in my use case. Thank you!